# How to use python library - import webbrowser in google colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science, google-colaboratory

I just started writing my machine learning program in Google Colab. But, before that, I was using Jupyter Notebook so I heard about Google Colab hence I want to give it try but I stuck at python library(import webbrowser)- how to use in Colab? If you guys have a solution then share it here.

Comment: is the same...you can install packages with a !pip install

Comment: you could do a little googling,  [Click here](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-google-colab-f2fff97f594c?gi=cf638d9ba05a)

Comment: `Google Colab` runs on server so `webbrowser` will run browser on server which can display window only on monitor connected directly to server - you will not see it on your local monitor.